# give javascript commands using firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have a page with a list of items and a pagination link:

```
<a class="paginationNext" href="JavaScript:updFormSubmit('OffSet=2','ZSearchForm')" style="">NEXT</a>
```

I need to jump to page 50 (offset=50), however by clicking on the link I can only advance page by page.

Is there any way I can use firebug's console to 'simulate' a click on

```
<a class="paginationNext" href="JavaScript:updFormSubmit('OffSet=50','ZSearchForm')" style="">NEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute the `updFormSubmit('OffSet=50','ZSearchForm')` in the console. (*and click the `run` button if you have multiline mode on*)

Comment: Thanks Gaby, that solved it! by any chance, do you know whether there is a way of opening that page in another tab?

Comment: @Patrick, you cannot do it the way it is being called.. if it actually loads another url, it might be possible, but if it just uses AJAX and brings back result, then you can't..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the selenium Add-on for Firefox. It allows you to record, edit, and debug tests automatically. Selenium can simulate all kind of user interaction.